# Nest JS unable to inject service into guard if used in module

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I created basic AuthGuard, but can't inject TokenService. I am getting this error:

> Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthGuard (?). Please verify whether [0] argument is available in the current context.

**app.module.ts:**

```
@Module({
    modules: [
        WorkModule,
    ],
    components: [TokenService],
})

export class ApplicationModule { }
```

**auth.guard.ts:**

```
@Guard()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private readonly tokenService: TokenService,
    ) { }
    public canActivate(dataOrRequest, context: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**work.module.ts:**

```
@Module({
    controllers: [WorkController],
    components: [WorkService],
})
export class WorkModule { }
```

**Update, work.service.ts**:

```
import { Component, Inject, HttpStatus, HttpException } from '@nestjs/common';
const dataStore = require('nedb');
const workDB = new dataStore({ filename: '../db/work.db', autoload: true });
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { WorkDay, WorkDayDTO } from './work.model';
import { WorkHelpers } from './work.helpers';

@Component()
export class WorkService {
    public async getWorkGraphic(month: number, year: number) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // logic here
        });
    }

    public async addOrUpdateWorkDay(day: WorkDayDTO) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // logic here
        });
    }

    public async removeWorkDay(workDayId: string) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // logic here
        });
    }
}
```

**But with this configuration everything is working:**

```
@Module({
    controllers: [
        WorkController,
    ],
    components: [TokenService, WorkService],
})

export class ApplicationModule { }
```

What exactly is causing this error and how can I get it work with 1st solution (Modules) ?

Comment: can you show us where you are using guard? Also, reason the second solution is working, is because `AuthGuard` is dependent on `TokenService` so you need to provide it to it somehow (it needs to be added to `components`)

Comment: @Mentos1386 Using as:
`@Get()
    @UseGuards(AuthGuard)
    public async getWorkGraphic() {
...
}`
 - In controller.
The another solution that I found was to create SharedModule where TokenService is registered and import this SharedModule to each module (WorkModule, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Is possible to show your TokenService and WorkerService?

You should register both always in your components to use inside all of application scope.

If you are using inside a specific module and trying to use in another module, probably you will not be able.

Another scenario. Imagine if you have A component registered in A module, B component registered in B module and imagine if ure trying to use A component inside of B module, you cant do that unless you register in Application Module or register inside A component inside B module(dont do that, only shared services should be used in all of the scopes, is just an architecture overview).

Comment: Added WorkService as you asked.